# Circular implementation of queue data structure using C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have written the following C++ code to implement a queue data structure. However, i have two problems:

1. Whenever i delete the front element, it works fine. However, when i press 2 to delete the front element even when the queue is empty, i get a message saying
   "Queue empty" followed by a 5 on the next line. How can i prevent the 5 from appearing and why is it coming?
2. When i completely fill the queue and want to display the contents, the queue is being printed infinitely without stopping. I think there is something wrong in the for loop in the display function. When the queue is not full, the display function works fine. How can i fix this?

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int data;
class queue {

    private:
        int front,rear,capacity,a[100];

    public:
        queue(int n)
        {
            rear=front=-1;
            capacity=n;
        }

        void enqueue(int n)
        {
            if(front==-1)
            {
                front++;
                rear=front;
                a[front]=n;     
                return; 
            }
            if(rear%capacity==(front-1)%capacity)
            {
                cout<<"Queue is full\n";
                return;
            }
            rear=(rear+1)%capacity;
            a[rear]=n;

        }

        int dequeue()
        {
            if(front==rear&&front==-1)
            {
                cout<<"Queue is empty";
                return 0;
            }   
            if(front==rear&&front!=-1)
            {
                data=a[front];
                front=rear=-1;
                return data;
            }

            data=a[front];
            front=(front+1)%capacity;
            return data;
        }

        void display()
        {
            int i;
            for(i=front;i!=rear+1;i=(i+1)%capacity)
            cout<<a[i]<<endl;
        }

};

main()
{
    int x,y,c;
    cout<<"Enter capacity\n";
    cin>>c;
    queue q(c);

    while(1)
    {
        cout<<"Select option 1.insert 2.delete 3.display 4.exit\n";
        cin>>x;
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1: cout<<"Enter the element\n";
                    cin>>y;
                    q.enqueue(y);
                    break;
            case 2: q.dequeue();
                    break;
            case 3: q.display();
                    break;
            case 4: exit(0);                    
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Question 1 says "when i press 3 to delete the front element" but 2 is the delete command, 3 is display.  Is this an error in the description, or does it mean that if you delete until the queue is empty then you display you see a '5' that is leftover data? That would indicate another problem with the display loop.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Fixed it!

Comment: The difficulty of telling apart a full queue and an empty queue reminds us of the fine line between genius and insanity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.Display of empty queue**

The deletion of elements even in the empty queue works well.  However the display of the empty queue has a problem:

When the queue is empty, `front` and `rear` are both -1.

The `for` loop starts with `i=front` so `i` is -1

The condition is `i != rear + 1;` , which is true the first time (as `-1 != 0`),  so the loop executes one time printing `a[-1]`, which is undefined behaviour. THerefore a garbage output.

**2.Filled queue**

When the queue is full, `front` is 0 and `rear` is `capactity-1`.

So you start your for loop with i being 0,  you then loop and print out every element.  The last element being with `i` being `rear` which is `capacity-1`

When iterating one step further,  you do `i = (i + 1) % capacity` With the current value of i, this is equivalent to i= `(capacity-1 + 1)% capacity` which will be 0 and here you start looping again !

With your increment, you'll never reach an end of loop condition.

**How to fix it ?**

Here a working version

```
void display()
{
    int i;
    if (front == -1)  // This is a special case
        cout << "No elements" <<endl;
    else              // now the general case: do the module in the loop body (i.e. uppon increment and success
        for (i = front; i != rear + 1; i++) 
            cout << a[i% capacity] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Nice. The problem is partially fixed. But suppose i do this - Add the elements 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to the queue and then delete 1 and 2. After this if i again insert 5 and 6, and display, the queue is printed infinitely again. How can i fix this?

Comment: I solved the problem in the above comment. Here:                                                                                                          
                                                                                                           for (i = front; i != rear; i=(i+1)%capacity) 
cout << a[i] << endl;
cout<<a[rear]<<endl;

Answer (score 1):

A simpler implementation of a circular queue (for integers in this case) in C++ is:

CircularQueue.h:

```
class CircularQueue
{
public:
    CircularQueue(int n);
    ~CircularQueue();
    bool Empty();
    bool Full();
    void push(int i);
    bool front(int& i);
    void pop();
private:
    int N;
    int Capacity;
    int* buffer;
    int head;
    int tail;
};
```

CircularQueue.cpp:

```
#include "CircularQueue.h"

CircularQueue::CircularQueue(int n) : N(n) {
    Capacity = N + 1;
    buffer = new int[Capacity];
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
}

CircularQueue::~CircularQueue()
{
    delete[] buffer;
}

bool CircularQueue::Empty()
{
    return head == tail;
}

bool CircularQueue::Full()
{
    return (head + 1) % Capacity == tail;
}

void CircularQueue::push(int i)
{
    if (!Full()) {
        buffer[head] = i;
        head = (head + 1) % Capacity;
    }
}

bool CircularQueue::front(int& i)
{
    if (!Empty()) {
        i = buffer[tail];
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

void CircularQueue::pop()
{
    if (!Empty())
        tail = (tail + 1) % Capacity;
}
```

Reference: http://www.drdobbs.com/thread-safe-circular-queue/184401814